# HttpContext.Current.Error.InnerException always return null value

Tags: c#, asp.net

`HttpContext.Current.Error.InnerException` always returns null value but I am getting the values in `HttpContext.Current.Error` and `Server.GetLastError()`.

My web.config file is

```
 <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="~/Error.aspx" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" />
```

Comment: Call `Exception.GetBaseException()`

Answer (score 0):

Probably just because there is not inner exception.

*An instance of Exception that describes the error that caused the current exception. The InnerException property returns the same value as was passed into the constructor, or a null reference (Nothing in Visual Basic) if the inner exception value was not supplied to the constructor*

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.innerexception%28v=vs.100%29.aspx